# Coupled Spring without damping has unbounded solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

From Newton's Second Law we get the system

$m_1x_1''=-k_1x_1 + k_2(x_2-x_1)$

$m_2x_2''= -k_2(x_2-x_1)$

If $m_1,m_2$ are both 1, $k_1$ and $k_2$ are both 1, and all initial conditions except $x_1'(0)=1$ are zero, then I end up with solutions that are unbounded.

My results are in here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gkmotdpqpy

where I have added a vertical shift to the first solution to make the graph easy on the eyes.

Since there is no damping force, I did not expect the magnitude to tend towards zero as $t\to\infty$. However, there are no driving forces either. I assumed that the motion of $m_1$ would "kick-start" the system into something periodic. Is my solution incorrect? Should this system be bounded?

Comment: To check if your equations are correct, look at the limit of what happens as you change some of the parameters to approach infinity or zero.  What happens if you drive k1 towards 0 and m2 towards infinity while keeping m1 and k2 at 1?

Comment: Yes, I think I have made a mistake in my calculations. There should not be unbounded solutions...